# Is import lots of stuff considered a React-specific thing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, eslint

I know the title might sound a little confusing.

I am working as an front end developer intern at some company and we use React as our framework. Normally when I write a new component or implement a new feature, I will have to import a lot of stuff, like `React` itself, lib like `lodash` and `moment.js`, also other `components` from the project.

So normally I would end up with like 20 to 30, even more `import` statements sitting at the top of the JS file.

I am not super knowledgable about other programming languages or frameworks and I understand they will probably import from other libraries as well. But since `React` has `components`, does this large amount of `import` happen rarely in other languages or frameworks?

Also, other question is, our company has a very rigid rule on the order of those `import` statements. e.g. first import external npm packages then second internal npm packages.

Is the reason for enforcing a consistent import convention just a stylistic choice? Or is there other utilitarian reasons?

Comment: The `import` *order* is purely stylistic.

Comment: 20 to 30 is a way too many. Try to go for 10 or less.